# sqlsrv_fetch_array broken from entry

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, while-loop, sqlsrv

I'm reading data from a Microsoft SQL Server database and I've got one row that literally "breaks the cycle", meaning I have to process something like 160.000 rows, but as soon as this particular row is encountered, the script stops executing and exits, like if it had finished to process the rows: no exception is thrown, no error, nor warning from php, nor from the mysql db in which i'm inserting the rows.. nothing, it just stops executing and prints me a custom message that tells me it has simply consumed all the rows, but this is not true as it processes only 50.000 entries.

I've checked the row and there are not strange characters ...

this is a part of the code:

```
   $tsql= "SELECT * FROM ordini_all ORDER BY id ASC";

$getResults= sqlsrv_query($msconn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

if ($getResults === FALSE){ die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));}

else{echo "ok query - Righe " . sqlsrv_num_rows($getResults) . "\n\n\n";}

// Create connection - to local mysql db

$mysql_conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($mysql_conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $mysql_conn->connect_error);}

$inizio = date("h:i:sa");

$counter = 0;

$err_counter = 0;

$tot_orders = sqlsrv_num_rows($getResults);

echo "\n Rows " . $tot_orders; //this is the correct number

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    ... do your things to insert rows in another db
}

echo "\nInizio " . $inizio . " Fine " . date("h:i:sa") . " tot errori " . $err_counter . " su inserite " . $counter . " il totale era " . $tot_orders .  "\n";
```

Cannot add the faulty entry, for privacy reasons, but it has nothing really different from all the other 159.999 entries.

Any clue on what could stop the execution of the while loop?

Comment: put try catch  and print the message

Comment: try to increase the timeout  . http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: it's not a question of timeout for sure. I've tried processing something like 10 rows, including that one and the loop breaks anyway. And no exception is thrown

Comment: So except for 1 row  everything is being processed?

Comment: i've tried to query the db before and after that row (not all the after ones but at least half) and everything is being processed, either successfully, either throwing error, but the loop keeps processing...

Comment: I would generally try and find the  1 row and then identify the column. Some columns may have invisible characters which are hard to find.

Comment: it's like the cursor is not able to go after that entry, it simply stops executing as if it was the end of the table. I was also thinking to a strange character but couldn't find it... i will try to exclude columns one by one, but it's hard to find as i have something like 80 columns hehe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167430/discussion-between-srp-and-sissy).

Comment: Did you every figure out what was causing this? Dealing with the same issue.