# sqlsrv_query stopping while encountering an error

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, sqlsrv

I'am trying to fetch data from my ms sql database. I use sqlsrv in php to make the connection and everything's working fine, perhaps it seems that my select has a problem and I think it has something to do with the char encoding.

My query :

```
SELECT TOP 100 NOM FROM SITE WHERE SITE.DATFINVAL IS NULL
```

My code :

```
$msconn = msdbConnect();
$ms_query = "SELECT TOP 100 NOM FROM SITE WHERE SITE.DATFINVAL IS NULL;
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($msconn, $ms_query);
if ($stmt === false) {
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo $row['NOM'] . "<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```

In fact, my select query works fine when executing it from the server itself, but when executing it using sqlsrv_query in php it stops where it encounters the 6th line which is "PDA BRUZ - N° 80100".

The results should display 100 lines of "NOM" but instead it only shows 5, which is weird because the query I use works fine in the SQL Server Management tool.

I also tried to only select the line 6 "PDA BRUZ - N° 80100" and it didn't worked with php. So I guess it's an encoding problem maybe due to the " ° " but I can't figure how to fix that, I already tried to paste this line of code just before the sqlsrv_query statement :

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

But it still doesn't work, I'm used to mysqli which rather than just stopping the select query would have shown the data but with an incorrect charset. How should I fix my dumb error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well my bad, I'm editing my question to make it fits the standards

Comment: What exactly do "it stops", "doesn't work", and "encountering an error" mean? There is no reason why the query itself does not produce the correct resultset regardless of encoding. Does that query "work" when run directly in SSMS query window? If it does, then the problem is in your application - you will need to post the relevant code that executes the query and processes the resultset.

Comment: Excuse my bad explanation, I just edited my question

Comment: I don't think that the `mssql.charset` directive has anything to do with the `sqlsrv` extension. Before Microsoft created its own, there used to be an old SQL Server extension called `mssql`, now seemingly gone from the documentation. Can you please add for `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` the same error checking you already do for `sqlsrv_query()`?

Comment: I just added the same error checking but for the fetch_array and nothing is reported so far. The result displayed still contians the 5 first lines rather than the 100 I ask for

Comment: I tried to display the number of rows using sqlsrv_num_rows and it returned me "100" which is the number of rows I expected.. Why can't I display the correct values using my previous code ?

Comment: "nothing is reported" - What does this mean exactly? Does `sqlsrv_query()` return `false` yet `sqlsrv_errors()` produce an empty array?

Comment: sqlsrv_errors() produce an array which seems not to contain any errors  and sqlsrv_query does not return false :

`[0] => 01004
            [SQLSTATE] => 01004
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation`

And sqlsrv_fetch_array returns the first 5 elements but I should have 100 results like in sql server management studio

Comment: The problem I encounter is the same as the one in this post :

[sqlsrv_fetch_array broken from entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455077/sqlsrv-fetch-array-broken-from-entry)

I tried everything he tried and I get the same behavior from php, the 6th line in the sql db contains "°" which I'm pretty sure is causing the problem, that's why I said the query seems to "stop" when encountering that row

Comment: Plus my SQL Table "SITE" is a Latin1_General_BIN which means all type of conversions are made according to the binary values. I'm sure the "°" is causing problem because when I edit it to an empty space my result shows all the lines I asked for.

Would it be possible to edit my SQL Query or something in PHP to convert to another encoding like ut8_general_ci ?

Comment: I successfully solved the problem by converting to nvarchar in the SQL Query, I'm posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who get in this situation, I found the solution by editing the SQL query from

```
SELECT TOP 10 NOM FROM SITE WHERE SITE.DATFINVAL IS NULL
```

To

```
SELECT TOP 10 CONVERT(nvarchar, NOM) FROM SITE WHERE SITE.DATFINVAL IS NULL
```

It definitely was a problem with encoding so I tried to convert the varchar(30) to nvarchar(30) which seems to be the correct way to retrieve datas using sqlsrv_fetch_array without it being stopped if it encounters a wrong special char.

Comment: You may try to change the encoding by addition `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` as additional option in `sqlsrv_connect()`. The default [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-ver15) is `SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR`

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems to work at first sight ! I'm still going to keep my CONVERT query but in addition of the CharacterSet => UTF-8